# Как сделать фильтр удаления сообщений discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Нужно что бы бот удалял все сообщения в чате, кроме помеченных. Например пользователе пишет в чат:

1

//2

3

4

И бот при использовании команды должен удалить все сообщения кроме 2-ой строки с пометкой //

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Да, такое возможно реализовать. В обработчике `on_message` проверяйте, чтобы сообщение начиналось с `//` и если это не так — то удаляйте сообщение.

Answer (score 1):

Просто сделайте проверку на наличие `//` в контенте сообщения:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if not '//' in msg:
        await message.delete()
```